# accelerate and memory optimize for loop

Tags: performance, matlab, memory

I have the following data types:

```
K1,K2,K3,K4 = ... % predefined constants which are not subject to change.  
time = 1e6; % time steps length.
z = 1e3; % location vector length.
A_Sink = rand(1,time);
B_Sink = rand(1,time);
laserA = zeros(1,z);
laserB = zeros(1,z);
laserA_Old = zeros(1,z);
laserB_Old = zeros(1,z);
```

Now here is the code:

```
for ii = 1:time
    laserA_Old = laserA;
    laserB_Old = laserB;
    laserA(2:end) = laserA_Old(2:end) + K1*diff(laserA_Old) + K2*laserB_old(2:end);
    laserA(1) = A_Sink(ii);        
    laserB(1:end-1) = laserB_Old(1:end-1) + K3*diff(laserB_Old) + K4*laserA_Old(1:end-1);
    laserB(end) = B_Sink(ii);
end
```

Now my main gripes are, I see in the profiler that the lines in the loop with `(2:end)` or `(1:end-1)` are allocating memory without freeing it. This causes MATLAB to be much slower.
Is there a way to accelerate things and improve it memory-wise?

many thanks.

Comment: Are K1-K4 scalars or vectors? If they're scalar (i.e. the vector length isn't critical), it might be better to remove the `(2:end)` and `(1:end-1)` entirely - the extra element won't matter since it gets directly overwritten afterwards, and you lose the overhead of indexing and a potential intermediate copy.

Comment: the problem is the diff. it creates an array of (n-1) size so removing the indices creates a problem.

Comment: Wow, it _is_ late, when did I start thinking `diff` was `sum`?! How does it fair if you index the vectors up front e.g. `LA_O=LA(2:end); LB_O=LB(2:end); LA=[A_S(ii), LA_O + K1*diff(LA) + K2*LB_O]...`? Ultimately I suspect `diff` may be the bottleneck rather than memory - I'd try splitting each addition into a separate line to get a better overview - I've also seen cases where splitting long statements into multiple small lines actually speeds things up anyway.

Comment: unfortunately no. I've tried it already and no sort of groundbreaking improvement has occured.